# Make a jQuery event happen once

Tags: jquery

I'm making a wordpress template.
Imagine I have a  that contains a menu bar with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#menu').hide();
      $('#menu').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

my menu slide down (it's a vertical menu), when the page loads...
but, everytime I load a new static page in wordpress (pageid=1 etc), the page reload itself and so the event restart and the menu slide down again every time I press a link in the website!

How can I make the menu sliding animation happends one time?
maybe only when I hit the home button and not all the pages?

Comment: A cookie would probably be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a session variable `$_SESSION['opened']==1;` only on homepage

in header where is that jquery code:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['opened']) && $_SESSION['opened'] == 1): ?>
```

your jquery code

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the rest of the pages, set that variable 0

Answer (score 1):

You could make this event happen only in your site's homepage, like:

```
<?php
if (is_home()):
?>
<style type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#menu').hide();
      $('#menu').slideToggle("slow");
});
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but if you want the user to see the animation even when he enters by any other page, you'll probably need some cookies ;P

Comment: by the way, this works is_home() is a wordpress function that checks if... well, if it is home :P